# How to build a small FSM on Arduino, why mine doesn't work?

Tags: arduino

```js
// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
    int voltage = analogRead(A0);
    pushNewData(voltage);
    if(data[SIZE-1] != 0){
        int average = (int)(calculateAVG(data));
        int sd = (int)(calculateSD(data));
        /*
        Serial.print(voltage);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(average);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.print(average+2*sd);
        Serial.print(",");
        Serial.println(average-2.5*sd);
        */
        if(voltage > average+2*sd || voltage < average+2.5*sd){
            interval = 5;
        }
        else{
            interval = 50;
        }

        //Serial.println(blinkElapsed);
        unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
        if(currentMillis - previous > interval) {
            // save the last time you blinked the LED 
            previous = currentMillis;   

            // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
            if (current_state == 1){
                Serial.println("1");
                led1_state = HIGH;
                led2_state = LOW;
                led3_state = LOW;
                digitalWrite(led1, led1_state);
                digitalWrite(led2, led2_state);
                digitalWrite(led3, led3_state);
                current_state = current_state + 1;
            }
            else if(current_state == 2){
                Serial.println("2");
                led1_state = LOW;
                led2_state = HIGH;
                led3_state = LOW;
                digitalWrite(led1, led1_state);
                digitalWrite(led2, led2_state);
                digitalWrite(led3, led3_state);
                current_state = current_state + 1;
            }
            else if(current_state ==3){
                Serial.println("3");
                led1_state = LOW;
                led2_state = LOW;
                led3_state = HIGH;
                digitalWrite(led1, led1_state);
                digitalWrite(led2, led2_state);
                digitalWrite(led3, led3_state);
                current_state = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

state is a global variable in the front. I hope these LEDs will blink one by one and with interval decided by sound level. But it just keeps running the state1 and never go to state2. I don't know why. Why it never get 1 added?

Comment: 1.  Try adding a final else that does `Serial.println(current_state)` to see if your state is ever wonky.  2.  Avoid subtraction with unsigned values (`currentMillis - previous > interval` would be safer as `currentMillis > previous + interval`), and make sure `previous` and `interval` are both declared as unsigned longs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reformatted your code a bit.

Now there are some things to check:

```
if(data[SIZE-1] != 0){
```

Does this ever evaluate to `true`? (it probably does since you're using some debug prints inside that block).

```
if(currentMillis - previous > interval) {
```

Is the variable `previous` properly initialized (outside the loop)? Like for example:

```
unsigned long previous = millis();
```

What is the initial value of `current_state`? If it is zero for example, none of the 3 blocks will ever be executed (and you might be looking at some default state).

You could also change the last `else if(current_state ==3){` to just `else{` to at least catch those problems - or even better, as Patrick suggests in the comments, add an extra `else` branch to catch a possible invalid `current_state`.

Also make sure `current_state` is not altered in any other function.

Comment: I don't see how the initialisation value of `previous` might cause **state 1** being repeatedly executed, as the user **claims** in his most recent comment. I am also against changing `else if (current_state == 3) {` into `else {`: it affects the semantics of the program. Perhaps appending an `else` branch is better.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Indeed, but I just added this in case the user was just looking at the LED's (which could be in a default ON/OFF/OFF state). If `previous` is undefined it could be that none of the blocks get executed. On the other hand, if the value "1" is printed in a loop, the only other possibility I see is that `current_state` is changed in one of the other functions.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin As for the else brach, you're right, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your finite state machine is "not finite."  State 3 should perhaps loop back to state 1, for one thing, so that the process has a chance of repeating.  The only way you can get back to `1` now is for state `3` to fire so many times that the `current_state` variable rolls to 4..5..6..integer maximum..0..1.

```
else if(current_state ==3){
  Serial.println("3");
  led1_state = LOW;
  led2_state = LOW;
  led3_state = HIGH;
  digitalWrite(led1, led1_state);
  digitalWrite(led2, led2_state);
  digitalWrite(led3, led3_state);
  current_state = 1;
}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, then let's start working backwards.  If the program is stuck with the first LED lit, then it's likely that this code

```
 else if(current_state == 2){
  //...
  current_state = current_state + 1;
}
```

never executed.  Therefore, would begin question whether my state machine was advancing states **at all.**  To learn whether that's happening, for the moment, let's reuse one of the output pins, `led3` as a sort of "heartbeat" pin.  So, farther up your code, insert the "flash LED3" snip like so:

```
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

// STOP FOR A SECOND TO TOGGLE THE STATE
if (led3_state == HIGH)
    led3_state = LOW;
else
    led3_state = HIGH;
// FLASH THE LED TO SEE IF WE'RE GETTTING HERE
digitalWrite(led3, led3_state);

// CONTINUE
if(currentMillis - previous > interval) {
```

You see, by moving this code block around we can figure out where we're getting to.  Now, this LED might flash very fast -- fast enough to appear continuously lit -- but it's a basic way to debug by learning that "yes, my code is reaching this point."  When you're working with a "computer" with no screen, no keyboard, no printer, nothing like that, and lacking an oscilloscope, sometimes this is all you can do.

So please do this, and keep moving this code block down until it quits working.  Then you will have found the statement that isn't working and we can go from there.  How's that sound?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected but the problem is that the arduino will keep running the state 1 and never go to other states.

Comment: Please see my extra answer text on how to proceed with debugging.